# How to remove a row from the dataset after finding the best combination from the list in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, numpy, matrix

Suppose `N = 7`.
I have 2 matrices Y and Z taken from my dataset M. 1st Column is the index `ID`.
Z matrix has been created by taking combination of 7 rows from the Y matrix(of 8 rows) having the max det value.
 I want to get that row which has been omitted from the combinations and then delete that row from my dataset M.

So I want to delete that 8th row from my original dataset M.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools as it
import io

def brute_force(A):
    return max(map(list,it.combinations(range(len(Y)),N)),
               key=lambda s: np.linalg.det(A[s].T@A[s]))

data =''' 
ID,M,N,O,P,Q,R
5362,0.974,-0.404,-0.763,0.868,-0.5,0.16
485,-0.659,0.531,0.623,0.402,0.772,0.506
582,0.045,0.994,0.762,-0.036,0.117,-0.355
99,0.777,0.537,0.391,0.456,0.329,0.108
75,-0.44,0.522,0.856,-0.04,0.656,-0.935
474,0.357,0.81,0.135,0.389,0.055,0.224
594,-0.291,0.031,0.742,-0.332,0.815,0.983
597,0.968,-0.357,0.591,0.892,0.375,0.88
124,0.737,0.611,0.764,0.289,0.298,-0.705
635,0.883,0.96,-0.987,0.29,0.997,0.186
7894,-0.045,0.047,0.523,0.068,-0.9,0.356
1268,0.561,0.736,-0.375,0.465,0.908,0.2
38,0.465,0.623,0.734,0.145,0.489,0.759
88,0.029,0.166,0.098,0.285,0.18,0.829
887,0.464,0.652,-0.896,0.07,0.772,-0.268
994,-0.611,0.986,0.708,-0.195,0.938,0.166
478,0.109,0.664,0.977,0.2,-0.466,0.676
693,0.893,0.536,0.827,0,0.658,-0.31
455,0.745,0.851,0.025,0.667,0.094,0.127
874,0.036,-0.212,0.879,0.966,0.788,0.719
417,0.316,0.553,0.872,-0.274,0.946,0.238
44,0.517,-0.113,0.992,0.521,0.595,0.674
101,0.699,0.095,0.269,0.628,-0.711,-0.141
60,0.993,0.348,-0.44,0.807,0.013,0.325
8741,-0.319,0.535,0.717,-0.89,0.334,0.279
9635,0.363,0.812,0.77,0.715,0.34,0.327
2563,0.649,-0.788,0.405,0.056,0.25,0.08
5463,0.491,0.414,0.084,0.173,0.397,-0.499
1044,-0.669,0.288,0.424,-0.324,0.491,-0.581
999,0.208,0.082,-0.425,0.916,0.582,0.45
'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data),index_col=0)
M = df.iloc[:,:]
N = int(input( '\nNo. of rows: '))

Y = M.iloc[0 : N+1 ,:]
print(Y.index)
YB = brute_force(Y.to_numpy())
Z = Y.iloc[YB]
print(Z.index)
```

Output:

```
No. of rows: 7
Y.index :  Int64Index([5362, 485, 582, 99, 75, 474, 594, 597], dtype='int64', name='ID')
Z.index :  Int64Index([5362, 485, 582, 99, 75, 594, 597], dtype='int64', name='ID')
```

Here Index `474` is not present in Z matrix after finding combinations from Y matrix. So I want to delete that complete row from my original dataset M. I want to use the reduced dataset M for further looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a set difference to find the missing index and [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) to remove it from `M`

```py
to_drop = (set(Y.index) - set(Z.index)).pop()

M = M.drop(to_drop, axis=0)
```